# Javascript Cross domain requests in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-domain, xdomainrequest

I have a function that verifies an ID against a database. If the ID is found, the function returns true and if not it returns false.

Got the request to work in the other browsers. Now working on figuring it out with Internet Explorer's XDomainRequest.

```
function verify(id){
    xmlhttp=new window.XDomainRequest();
    xmlhttp.onload = checkResponse;
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://abc.com/verify?id=" + encodeURIComponent(id));
    xmlhttp.send();

    function checkResponse(){
        if(xmlhttp.responseText == 200) {   
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I want the verify function to return false, not the checkResponse function.

In other browsers setting the open to false does the trick but not in IE.

No jQuery answers please.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: making AJAX synchronous defeats it's purpose.

Comment: Do you have another suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the recommended way to incorporate CORS requests in IE8 into jQuery. You could probably use this as a starting point for your own:

https://github.com/jaubourg/ajaxHooks/blob/master/src/ajax/xdr.js

Also, `verify` shouldn't be a synchronous operation. Would recommend passing a callback function to it and keeping it async:

```
function verify(id, callback){
    var xmlhttp = new window.XDomainRequest();
    xmlhttp.onload = function () {
        callback( xmlhttp.responseText === 200 );
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://abc.com/verify?id=" + encodeURIComponent(id));
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Which you could then call like so:

```
verify( 123456, function ( isValid ) {
    if ( isValid ) {
        // do something if valid
    } else {
        // or not
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm trying to incoporate this. The function is synchronous because it's used to load a different UI based on the ID being in the database or not.

Comment: That may be the case, but then you will disallow the user from making any interactions at all on the page. Better to leave it async.

Answer (score -2):

the first point you need to consider is changing you js code to work as non asynchronous. Otherwise the checkResponse is the only point you have to get an answer. Your code seems to be asynchronous, and it should be synchronous.

Regards.

Comment: How do you suggest making it synchonous?

Comment: Yeah, definitely do not recommend making it synchronous. You will block the UI while waiting for a response.

Comment: Checking the information in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288168%28v=vs.85%29.aspx it seems that your call can't support synchronous calls, so you should change your code, and you should use a callback function.